# Using Python to read CSV and plot 5 series over time based on column condition

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to graph a series of 5 lines onto one plot with a dataset from a "data.csv" file in python.  There are hundreds of columns in the dataset, but I am only interested in "Time", "Value", and "Machine" columns.

I've got far enough to plot value over time all together, but I would like to have a line graph of the "Value" over "Time" with each "Machine" as a separate series.

My dataset looks sometime like this
[Table of Time, Value, Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbZGg.png)

What is the best method to graph the "value" in each series conditionally based on "machine" numbers 1->5?

Here is the basic code I have so far to get a straightforward plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

value = df['Conductivity']
time = df['Local Timestamp']
machine = df['CWE Requestor']

plt.plot(time, value)
plt.ylabel('value')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.lineplort(data=df, x='Local Timestamp', y='Conductivity', hue='CWE Requestor')`